# Laravel 5 installing error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

**Steps I've done:**

1. I created a folder named 'laravel_5'.
2. open 'cmd' then typed 'cd D:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_5'.
3. re-enter 'D:' to change directory.
4. now I'm in the directory 'D:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_5'.
5. I input the command 'composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist' found in the laravel website.

**Error occurred:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you create new project using composer, it will automatically create project folder for you.

Go to `D:\xampp\htdocs` and change your composer command to this:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel laravel_5 --prefer-dist
```

**Or**

If you still facing problem while using composer to create laravel project then simply go to github and **clone the repo** or **download the zip** and do `composer update` within your application directory.

```
https://github.com/laravel/laravel.git
```